# Python: how to merge two dataframes and count over the days?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1
       Name           t
0      John   2017-10-05 21:17:14
1      John   2017-10-05 22:05:13
2      John   2017-11-05 21:05:13
3      Sarah  2017-10-05 09:17:14
4      Sarah  2017-11-05 09:17:14


df2
       Name           t
0      John   2017-10-05 11:17:14
1      Sarah  2017-10-05 22:05:13
2      Sarah  2017-11-05 21:05:13
3      Sarah  2017-11-05 19:17:14
4      Sarah  2017-11-05 12:17:14
```

I would like to count how many times each name appear every day

```
df3
       Name       t          count
0      John    2017-10-05      3
1      John    2017-11-05      1
2      Sarah   2017-10-05      2
2      Sarah   2017-11-05      4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), last convert `MultiIndex Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `name` parameter:

```
df1['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['t'])
df2['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['t'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.groupby(['Name', df['t'].dt.date]).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
    Name           t  count
0   John  2017-10-05      3
1   John  2017-11-05      1
2  Sarah  2017-10-05      2
3  Sarah  2017-11-05      4
```

Comment: Neat! I just have not found the trick with  `.reset_index(name='count')` clearly described in the pandas docs but it works.

Comment: Got it. Thx! Just confused it with `.DataFrame.reset_index()` before.